# Не работает плавное перемещение к якорю на Jquery

Tags: jquery

К примеру, у меня есть ссылка:

`<a href="#top"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up" id="backtotop"></i></a>` ,

которая должна перекинуть на этот div `<div id="top"></div>` ( он находится сверху в хидере), но она не срабатывает, я не могу понять почему, так как делал по примеру.

Вот Jquery:

```
$('#top').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = this.hash,
$target = $(target);

$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
window.location.hash = target;
});
});
```

Comment: А jquery подключено?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает консоль?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("a.click_me").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="click_me" href="#top">
  <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up" id="backtotop"></i>
</a>
```